# Conference-mode IEEE authors are not correctly aligned when they are on two lines

Tags: ieeetran, author

This is an excerpt directly copied from the example provided by IEEE conferences:

[image]

as you can see, the first and fourth names are not aligned... and generally, that's quite awful. Can I fix it?

```latex
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\title{Conference Paper Title*\\
{\footnotesize \textsuperscript{*}Note: Sub-titles are not captured in Xplore and
should not be used}
\thanks{Identify applicable funding agency here. If none, delete this.}
}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{3\textsuperscript{rd} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{4\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{5\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{6\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This document is a model and instructions for \LaTeX.
This and the IEEEtran.cls file define the components of your paper [title, text, heads, etc.]. *CRITICAL: Do Not Use Symbols, Special Characters, Footnotes, 
or Math in Paper Title or Abstract.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEEEtran` uses an *ad-hoc* environment instead of the standard tabular for this arrangement; I found a way to adjust it without patching the format.

Just change the `\and` after the third  author with:

```
\and[\hfill\mbox{}\par\mbox{}\hfill]
```

and you'll obtain:

[image]

This "special" command just should be used when you finish one line of author blocks and you want to start a new line.